# Complex Finite Dimensional Representation of GL(N,C)

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, geometric-langlands, langlands-conjectures

What are all the complex finite dimensional linear representation of $GL(N,\mathbb{C})$?

We already know all the complex finite dimensional linear representation of SU(N).

Comment: No extra hypotheses? You don't want it to be algebraic? Analytic? Smooth? Continuous? 

Comment: And what does this have to do with geometric Langlands? 

Comment: I see that you've asked a number of other questions, many appropriate for this site. This particular question is more appropriate for Google.

Comment: does finite dimensional imply analytic and smooth?

Comment: Finite-dimensional does not imply analytic and smooth. We can use wild
automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$ that permute a transcendence basis. If
you don't like this, there are also the non-analytic representations
$A\mapsto |\det(A)|$ and $A\mapsto \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & \log
|\det A|\\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right]$.


Comment: The context of the question is unclear, but, ... At least probably one wants to assume _continuity_ of the repn. Continuity certainly does imply _smoothness_, because even in infinite-dimensional (continuous) repns, Garding's argument proves density of smooth vectors, which in a finite-dimensional repn must be everything. A refinement of such an argument proves that _real_ analytic vectors are dense in "nice" repns, and finite-dimensional are nice enough so that all vectors are real-analytic. But, as Richard S. notes, certainly not complex-analytic. Then it's about highest weights? Clarify?